# Remote machine doesn't ask for git user/password for private repo while accessing through VSCode-Remote-SSH terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I ssh to an aws ec-2 from VSCode using Remote-SSH and opened the terminal tried to pull a private repo and it pulled without asking a user name or password.

How come is this possible? A security flaw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a feature of VSCode-Remote-SSH with [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github)

Once you configured your VSCode with Github [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) it takes advantage of that configuration in a remote machine as well. That's why it doesn't ask for user name or password.